# Split array into different sized chunks

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of 6 elements A[0,1,2,3,4,5] and I have another of 3 elements B[2,1,3].

I want to split array A into 3 chunks based on the values in array B, as follows:
Array[0,1]
Array[2]
Array[3,4,5]

I then want to create a third array that that takes element 0 of each new array and create a new array, as follows:

new array[0,2,3]

Can any one give me an idea how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please don't ask us to do your homework.

Comment: What is the logic behind splitting it like this?. What eactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you need those intermediate arrays at all, or just the final one?

Comment: It's most likely about segmented vectors, like in http://blog.theincredibleholk.org/blog/2013/04/11/data-parallel-data-structures/

Comment: For or (maybe) System.arraycopy (You already know it's 3 elements in B?)

Comment: @RohitJain I posted this question but in the meantime I was working on  a solution on my own. It was critical I got this issue resolved ASAP so I posted for hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this time. But next time, as [Rohit Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679863/rohit-jain) said, do some research, try on your on. You don't learn how to program or think logical by delegating your tasks to others.

The function

```
public int[] foo(final int[] values, final int[] sizes) {
    final int[] results = new int[sizes.length];
    int         index  = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
        if (index > values.length)
            break;

        results[i]  = values[index];
        index     += sizes[i];
    }

    return results;
}
```

And example call:

```
final int[] values     = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,};
final int[] sizes      = new int[] {2, 1, 3};

final int[] fooedArray = foo(values, sizes);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in the final result, you would not need to create the intermediate arrays and simply use indexes and a loop over the arrays:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] b = new int[] { 2, 1, 3 };

int indexA = 0;
int indexB = 0;
int[] result = new int[b.length];
while (indexA < a.length && indexB < b.length) {
    result[indexB] = a[indexA];
    indexA += b[indexB];
    indexB++;
}
for (int r : result) {
    System.out.println(r);
}
```